# Flink streaming - cartesian product and windowing over streams

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Assume that I have a stream with keys and timestamps. I want to create the cartesian product of these keys in each window (sliding window). If I have the keys 1,2,3,4 and I have set the parallelism to two, I want to "group" them in the following manner:

```
1 - 2    2 - 3
1 - 3    2 - 4
1 - 4    3 - 4
```

And I want to process the elements per group per window. So imagine that the above elements (1,2,3,4) are in the same window, based on their timestamps.

In the simplest form my question is: given some elements in each sliding window (which might contain several keys), I want to create the combinations of those keys as in the example above and apply a custom algorithm over those grouped elements.

What I have tried so far, is the use of

```
.assignAscendingTimestamps(...)
.keyBy(...)
.timeWindow(Time.seconds(5),Time.seconds(5))
.apply(...)
```

but this will only apply an algorithm per key, plus the combinations cannot be created.

P.S.: I have seen this document: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Streams+and+Operations+on+Streams

and I think that the discretized streams mentioned there would do the trick, but they are not available in flink 1.2 (or any other version).

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting this right, but **"given some elements in each sliding window (which might contain several keys)"** can't work with the given example, because you create a `timeWindow` on a `KeyedStream`. Thus all elements within your `timeWindow` will have the exact same key.

Comment: You understood correctly. I want each sliding window to have several keys. Given a stream, I want to create all possible pairs of keys and process those pairs together in a sliding window.

Answer (score 2):

The `keyBy()` in the in the streaming context has a comparable effect to the `groupBy()` in the batch processing context. Based on the `KeySelector` that you provide the stream is partitioned into a number of sub-streams. Those are then fed into your `timeWindow`. Thus what you're currently doing in you example is a `timeWindow` on a `KeyedStream`. All elements that get into your `timeWindow` and are emitted into the function you apply afterwards will have the exact same key. Here's a nice introduction to windowing in Flink that goes into some more detail on how to use windows https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/12/04/Introducing-windows.html.
If your keys contain semantic information and you want to have different keys within the same window, you can create an artificial key (e.g. a simple integer) that you assign to your records. Based on this key, you have more control over grouping and thus stream partitioning. 
For your final computation that takes the results of the previous steps and joins them, you'll need an additional step (e.g. `join` or `reduce`). 
Take a look at the first example here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/datastream_api.html
It counts all elements with a given key over a `timeWindow` of 5 seconds using the `sum()` function. The result will contain one element per key per window.

Comment: If your keys contain semantic information and you want to have different keys within the same window, you can create an artificial key (e.g. a simple integer) that you assign to your records. That is a very logical approach, but what happens when you want all possible pairs between the keys? How can one implement that with Flink?

Comment: If you look at the result that you get from the `sum()` operation in the example from the Flink documentation, you get a ` DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>>`. In general, `sum()` returns a `Datastream` and thus you can perform any transformation on the result that is allowed for `Datastreams` like `map()` or `flatMap`. The release docs here https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/datastream_api.html give you a nice overview of what operations can be performed on which input and what comes out of the data in the end.